# Window handle inside for loop and move to second page after all links/windows have been opened and closed on current/first page - Java Selenium

Tags: java, loops, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code loops through first page links (*I'm using SHIFT action to perform opening new window*) then I'm collecting wanted data, after that I close new window and move to antoher link.
Everything works just fine, **BUT when I try to move on another/second page (with click) it seems like it's too late and I' getting this error (nine links on first page):**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 9
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)

**How to move on second page and keep looping through links on that second page, then third page and so on...**
Here is the code:

```
package Scrape;

   import java.io.File;

   public class Datascrape {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, 
    IOException {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get(page url);

    // list of all links on first page  

    List<WebElement> lista1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(""));

    // looping through those links            
       for (int j=0;j<=lista1.size(); j++){

    // click on link and open it in new window             
        WebElement link = lista1.get(j); 
        Actions newwin = new Actions(driver);
     newwin.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(link).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();

     //  switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (newly opened 
         window)

         String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
         for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
         driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); 
         }

     //  do something here

    // close newly opened window when done with it and switch back to the 
    //   original window
            driver.close(); 
            driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);

            }

   // TRY CLICK ON BUTTON AND MOVE TO ANOTER PAGE BUT IT's ALREADY TOO 
   //   LATE PROGRAM STOPS AND ERROR MESSAGE APPEARS ???

              driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();

             }
             }
```

Comment: Try changing `j<=lista1.size()` to `j<lista1.size()`

Comment: Simple and effective. Thank you so much.